# Boot android x86 installed on disk image file with grub

Tags: grub2, android-x86

I have it installed on a file a86.img in disk which I boot with qemu. Here is what I have so far but it gets stuck at Detecting Android x86...

```
menuentry "Android x86" --class android {
    savedefault
    loopback a86 (hd0,3)/vm-disks/a86.img
    set root='(a86,1)'
    linux /android-9.0-r2/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/android-9.0-r2
    initrd /android-9.0-r2/initrd.img
}
```